# Is there any security concerns implementing shared web credential in ios apps?

Tags: ios

according to apple guidelines : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials/managing_shared_credentials

Do not use the shared web credentials as your primary storage for secure user credentials. Instead, save the user’s credentials in the keychain, and only use the shared web credentials when you can’t find the login credentials in the keychain.

how far is this true? does it have any security concerns ? can the credential retrieved by an hacker ?

Comment: yes of course. 

- The stored credentials can be retrieved by hacker.
- Its better to store it in keychain or use certificate pining while calling the api's

Comment: how about if we whitelist the application ?

Comment: and the stored credentials can be retrieved by hacker only from jailbroken device ?

Comment: Please check this link:
https://www.cnet.com/news/keysteal-exploit-attacks-macos-keychain-to-take-all-your-passwords/#:~:text=An%20exploit%20called%20KeySteal%20can%20access%20your%20passwords%20in%20your%20Mac's%20keychains.&text=A%20malicious%20app%20running%20on,teenage%20security%20researcher%20has%20found.&text=Apple%20security%20researcher%20Patrick%20Wardle,and%20can%20confirm%20it%20works.

Comment: According to Apple, this keychain bug seems to have been addressed in macOS Sierra 10.12.6, macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, and macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and later.,

Comment: Can i get more information on this ? does it require jailbroken device ? how exactly hacker can perform attack to retrieve the credential ? if credentials doesn't get deleted after application deletion, that seems to be intentional so that other application of same service can access for it.